# Unity 3D VR, Grab an object located on the surface of another object

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

When working on a virtual reality project with Unity3D, I try to pick up an object that is placed on the surface of another object using the hand controller, but most of the time it picks up the surface object instead of the one I was aiming for.

I hope that there is a method to grab the object in question instead of the surface object.

Answer (score 0):

Just Reduce Colliers radius in hands gameobject